# How to resolve cmake directory libz.so.1 conflict with library in implicit directories of anaconda python? python

Tags: python, cmake, paraview

I'm trying to build an example using cmake which needs python and mpi.I have several python versions installed, pvpython python ipython and anaconda python. I set normal python in my PATH variable (I'm working in ubuntu-linux)
I'm new to cmake stuff. Some people stated I have to change   toolchainfile.cmake but I cannot locate it in my example files. Any lead on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!
Following is the  error I get while running ccmake.

```
    CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
```

Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target Fortran90FullExample
   because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
   directories:

```
runtime library [libz.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by
files in:/home/xxx/anaconda/lib
runtime library [libpython2.7.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be
hidden by files in:
/home/xxx/anaconda/libSome of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

Comment: Can you past the cmakelists.txt code? I don't think setting the correct python in the path is enough, you should check the python related variables in the cmake configuration (use ccmake, then press "t" to toggle to advanced view). Recently I had a problem which seemed related to http://public.kitware.com/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=9897 , hope that helps

Comment: anyway what you post is a warning, not an error, are you able to continue the configuration anyway?

Comment: Yes I was able to configure it. But after the make run generated errors.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the file libz.so.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory and it was in it. So I set the paths specifically for this directory and not the anaconda directories.

This time I used ccmake instead of cmake and I was able to easily give the paths on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu instead of the anaconda paths.
Also I changed my python path from anaconda python to the usual python location which was /usr/bin for me.

I added this to the path 
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
This adds it to the front of the PATH variable and does not effect what is already there.
Also I had to set PYTHONHOME=$PYTHONPATH to get rid of all the relatedd errors

Comment: Could you include terminal commands you have used to solve it please?